# Verify PHP session variable stored in Redis and Accessing it with another application

Tags: php, session, redis

I have installed redis and am looking to store the PHP session variables in redis. I installed PHP Redis and added the following in my php.ini file

```
extension=redis.so

session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379/"
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I verify if the session variable I am creating is getting stored in Redis as opposed to standard file system.
2. I am building a nodejs application for which I would need to access these session variables. How do I do that? How can the session variables be accessed by another application?

Comment: Run `redis-cli monitor` and you can watch what redis is doing.  Or you can look for the key.  If you know the key then do this from the redis-cli: `get <keyname>`, or just get a list of keys (assuming you have a manageable number) by running `keys *`

Comment: Note that the redis session save handler has a very nasty issue with not locking session access: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/339 You can destroy your session data, especially when using Ajax excessively.

Comment: The original issue probably is https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to check this is :

Step 1: Issue 'flushall' command on your redis database which is connected through tcp. This will flush all PHP Session values ( If any ).

Step 2: Login to your application. If it is configured properly, this should store a new PHP Session variable in the Redis Database.

Additional Step : Issuing flushall command again will delete the Session variable. When you go back and refresh your application, then it should logout automatically  due to loss of session value stored in Redis.